# add prebuilt jar to AOSP

Tags: jar, android-source, android-proguard

I am trying to add a prebuilt jar to Android when I compile AOSP.
The name of the jar is "nxpnfclib.jar" and I put it to AOSP/prebuilts/misc/common/nxp. I also write a Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    nxpnfclib$(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

include $(BUILD_HOST_PREBUILT)
```

I want to use this jar in AOSP/packages/apps/Settings, so I add nxpnfclib to AOSP/packages/apps/Settings/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := guava android-support-v4 jsr305 nxpnfclib
```

However, when I compile the whole AOSP, some errors occur:

> Warning: class [com/nxp/nfclib/ntag/╦К.class] unexpectedly contains
>   class [com.nxp.nfclib.ntag.ˊ] Warning: there were 30 classes in
>   incorrectly named files.
>            You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
>            The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
>            If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
>            you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option. Error: Please correct the above warnings first. make: ***
>   [out/target/common/obj/APPS/Settings_intermediates/proguard.classes.jar]
>   Error 1

How can I fix this error? It may come from proguard.

Is there some other way to add the jar?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Create one more directory libs into src and place the jar file into it. Then add these few more lines to Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += nxpnfclib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES:=nxpnfclib:src/libs/nxpnfclib.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Answer (score 0):

To build prebuilt jar to AOSP pls using BUILD_PREBUILT in Android.mk like below

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := nxpnfclib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nxpnfclib.jar # path to your jar file
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

To use this library in AOSP/packages/apps/Settings, pls add `nxpnfclib` to `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` in Android.mk of Settings like this:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += nxpnfclib
```